# Unable to fire ButtonClick event from ModalPopUp

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Script**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
             $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                 title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {

                 },
               modal: true
             });
             return false;
         });

    </script>
```

**Pop Up Div**

```
    <div id="modal_dialog" style="display: none">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload6" CssClass="CS" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnpopupupload" runat="server" Text="UPLOAD" onclick="btnpopupupload_Click"/>
    </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void btnpopupupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I am able to fire buttonclick event when the same button is outside the `modal_dialog` div.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $(document).on("click","[id*=btnModalPopup]" function () {
    $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
        },
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Its better to give a class name for the button, because .net will change the id of your button while rendering

or You can use

```
$(document).on("click",".classname" function () {
    $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
        },
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: do you have any serverside click event for that function?

Comment: Yes I do, I have `btnpopupupload_Click` in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

```
$('body').on("click", "[id*=btnModalPopup]"function () {
    $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
        title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
        buttons: {

        },
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I cant see my modal pop up now

Answer (score 0):

Change your button control to link button control as below.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnpopupupload" runat="server" Text="UPLOAD" onclick="btnpopupupload_Click"/>
```

If the above solution not working, please add below code in your script.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
         $("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
             $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                 title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {

                 },
               modal: true
             }).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
             return false;
         });

    </script>
```